# cargo install: specify a /tmp substitute?

Tags: rust-cargo

`cargo install` says:

```
error: failed to write /tmp/rustcaq37XH/lib.rmeta: No space left on device (os error 28)
```

Therefore I would like to tell Cargo to use some other directory than `/tmp`. As far as I can see, there is no environment variable or configuration option to set that. What can I do?

Thanks in advance,

Bertram

Answer (score 3):

The key to the soulution is the term "temporary target". As the documentation says, you can point that to a relative directory.

```
cd ~/.cargo
mkdir tmp
CARGO_TARGET_DIR=tmp cargo install mdbook
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for this, the same issue was bugging me for a long time. Second, is it safe to delete the 'temporary target' afterwards? Cargo doesn't clean it autmatically, and it has 12.1 GiB in my case

Comment: I would suggest if you still want the binary to end up somewhere you'd expect rather than then /tmp directory, you should also add either `--root /usr/local` or `CARGO_INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/local` otherwise the software you compile ends up in the temporary build location and doesn't get moved elsewhere.